# Why does my forloop + if/else console log an undefined value

Tags: javascript, for-loop, undefined

Given the following code, which works, and prints out all colors that are `red`, why does it also print out an `undefined` value at the end of the interations?

`var cars` is just a large array of car-objects with various properties.

```
function queryCars(){

  // Your code here
   for (var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++ ){
      if(cars[i].color == "Red") {
        console.log(cars[i].make + " " + cars[i].model)
      }
   }

}
```

Result:

```
queryCars();
"Audi A5"
"Audi TT"
"BMW 3"
"BMW X5"
"Hyundai Elantra"
"Acura TLX"
undefined
```

Comment: are you calling `console.log` somewhere else , ie directly after `queryCars()` ?

Comment: because either of cars[i].make Or cars[i].model is undefined

Comment: @DacreDenny nope... that is the only time it is called.

Comment: You can just do console.log(cars[i]) to debug this yourself. Without looking at your data it's hard to know, but I think @PiyushKhanna has the answer.

Comment: building on what @DacreDenny said, this undefined doesn't appear to be coming from the console.log in the for loop, because you'd have more than just 1 undefined if it were.

Comment: @PiyushKhanna all cars in the array have both a valid make and model.

Comment: yes @ODYN-Kon that's what I'm seeing also - @acd37 in dev tools, click on the line number next to `undefined` - it should take you to where  `undefined` is logging - is it in your loop ?

Comment: here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/DocZer0/pen/KrNyVy?

Comment: Try entering `queryCars() || 1` in the console, and think about that for a moment.

Comment: @DacreDenny there is no line number listed next to the undefined

Comment: @trincot not super helpful... I've been thinking about this for a while and the reason I came to Stack OverFlow is because I wanted/needed others' input on this

Comment: I am asking you to think about a variation. Did you notice it? Share what you think of it? Do you know what `|| 1` does?

Comment: Not seeing a undefined in the codepen

Comment: @trincot yes I am aware... I'm also aware I can return any other integer or string value here, but that's not the goal, the goal is to console log the list and exit. I've been developing for some time, but not managed to wrap my head around what seems to be a simple issue

Comment: I hoped you would see that the last output you see is the *evaluation of the expression* you type in the console. Your question was "Why". The answer has been given.

Comment: Looks like @Bergi is correct... it's just an intricacy of the Chrome/Firefox browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `undefined` is not coming from the `console.log`.  It's the return value of the function, since function is not returning anything.

For example, in repl.it:

```
let a
let b
console.log(a + " " + b)
```

prints:

```
undefined undefined
=> undefined
```

Not that the `console.log` would have printed 2 `undefines` if it were part of that loop.

Comment: Right.. so I understand that it is the return value of the function... nothing returned, thus undefined. 

But is there a way to fix it? I can't return inside the loop because then it stops the loop. I can return outside of the loop, and return something like "Done.", but I just want it to console.log the list and exit...

Comment: You don't need to fix it.  It's fine as is.  It's just the behavior of the script executor. If you insist on not having that last define, you can return "".